# Is there maven dependency:get analog in sbt?

Tags: java, scala, maven, dependencies, sbt

How can I download dependency with sbt? With maven it is:

```
mvn dependency:get
```

Is there analog in sbt?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no single `sbt` command that can be used for this. However,  `sbt` provides a `dependencyResolution` task key that can be used to implement a [custom task](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html) to download a single jar from a repository.

Here is an example implementation (add this to the `build.sbt`):

```
lazy val downloadArtifact = taskKey[Unit]("Download an artifact")
downloadArtifact := {
  val module = "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.2"
  val dr = dependencyResolution.value
  val files = dr.retrieve(
    dr.wrapDependencyInModule(module exclude("*", "*")),
    retrieveDirectory = new File("target"),
    log = (streams in Compile).value.log
  ).fold(e => throw e.resolveException, identity(_))
  println(files)
}
```

Caveats:

- By default, recent sbt versions use coursier for dependency resolution, and coursier has a bug where it ignores the `retrieveDirectory` argument (see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5465). This means that downloaded files won't be placed into the `retrieveDirectory` even though the API assumes that. You can either disable coursier and use ivy instead (`useCoursier := false`), or copy the files yourself to the desired destination (the `files` value above is a `List[java.io.File]` with the downloaded files.

Notes:

- `DependencyResolution.retrieve` downloads the artifact and all of its dependencies. This is why `exclude("*", "*")` is added above - to only download the artifact itself and exclude all of its dependencies.
- Even if you retrieve a single dependency, with coursier this function may produce a list of multiple file locations (I assume that this is due to the specificities of the dependency resolution logic). You are OK to use any file from the list since, normally, all of them point to the same file.
- Since this implementation uses the sbt's `dependencyResolution`, it respects any custom resolvers (custom repositories) that you may have declared in the sbt project.

---

Finally, although this isn't integrated with `sbt`, but maybe worh noting that if you happen to have [coursier](https://get-coursier.io/) installed you can use [coursier fetch](https://get-coursier.io/docs/cli-fetch):

```
cs fetch com.typesafe.scala-logging::scala-logging:3.9.2
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless I misunderstand [the documentation of `mvn dependency:get`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html), the equivalent in sbt is

```
> update
```

See [Dependency Management Flow](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Dependency-Management-Flow.html)

Comment: `mvn dependency:get` allows you to donwload artifact from repository to the local folder. So sbt update is not about this.